# looping through several columns and rows from csv to fill a form

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

Have been trying to emulate examples posted earlier, yet got stuck.

I have a simple web form: Last name, name, email, password, confirm password.

Also a .csv with 4 columns that corresponds to the form

```
Last name         Name             Email   Password
0    Brown        Stan     brown@stan.com   12345678
1    White        Eagle   white@eagle.com  123456789
2    Dante        Aligr     adant@mail.au   98765432
```

So, all I want is to feed the 3 entries to the form and click "Sent" after each entry.

I copycated a code from here that seemed passing but I keep getting this

```
  File "C:\Users\untitled2.py", line 43, in <module>
    last.send_keys(lname)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

the code I tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

options = Options()
options.binary_location = FirefoxBinary(r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\WebDriver\bin\geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=options)

import time
import pandas as pd

reg = pd.read_csv('Form.csv', header=0, delimiter=';', sep=r'\s*;\s*')

print(reg)

lname = reg['Last name'].tolist()
name = reg['Name'].tolist()
mail = reg['Email'].tolist()
password = reg['Password'].tolist()
password_c = reg['Password'].tolist()


driver.get('url')

first = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
last = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
mail =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
password =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
password_confirm = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")

submit = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/span')

for lname, name, mail, password, password_c in zip(lname, name, mail, password, password_c):
    
    last.send_keys(lname)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    first.send_keys(name)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    mail.send_keys(mail)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    password.send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    password_confirm.send_keys(password_c)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    submit.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Any nudge into the right direction will be highly appreciated since I have seen plenty of examples of using lists with send_keys()

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are using `send_keys()` with plain python `list`s.

According to [Selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), `find_elements_by_xpath` does indeed return a list.

It's possible that you meant to use `find_element_by_xpath` (without the 's' after element)?

Comment: Well, in fact it worked to some extend - it allowed to solve the list-problem. Also I found some mistakes - <br/> ``` mail = reg['Email'].tolist()
password = reg['Password'].tolist() ``` need to be <br/> ``` mail_ = reg['Email'].tolist()
password_ = reg['Password'].tolist()

Comment: Now I am onto automation = off. Will upload the solution if I get one

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow,

the execution part should have look like this

```
for lnames in lname:
    count = 0

for names in name:
    count_name = 0

for mails in mail_:
    count_mail = 0

for value in last:
    value.send_keys(lname[count])
    count +=1 
   
for x in mail:
    x.send_keys(mail_[count_mail])
    count_mail +=1 
    
for y in first:
    y.send_keys(name[count_name])
    count_name +=1
                                                                                                                                                                                         
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/span')
submit.click()
```