# Use loop to automated filling forms from a csv: loop repeats before form submission

Tags: python, forms, selenium, loops, csv

I have a script that automatically fills a web form with data from csv using a loop function.
My problem is that the script loops before submitting the form. So all of the row data for each column is pasted into each corresponding form field instead of pasting in a single row's data for each form field, submitting, and then looping to the next row.

I assume the issue is that the website requires users to confirm the address from a list of options before submission is finalized (usually the first address selected from a list of options is the correct one). If this is not done, the submission fails and the loop pastes in data from the next row.

Is it possible for the script to have a 20 second delay before looping so that I can review the address options field before the script submits the form, and then loops again for the next row of data? Or even better, I would like the script to automatically confirm the address from the first list of address options and then submit.

Thank you all!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv
import time
import pandas as pd

# import csv file
table = pd.read_csv('...test2.csv')

print(table)

address1 = table['Address2'].tolist()
unit1 = table['Unit2'].tolist()
unittype1 = table['Unit Type'].tolist()
beds1 = table['Beds2'].tolist()
bath1 = table['Baths2'].tolist()
rent1 = table['Rent2'].tolist()

# open chrome
# driver = Webdriver.chrome("C:\Python Tools\chromedriver.exe")
s = Service("C:\Python Tools\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

# Enter login
driver.get("https://hadashboard.gosection8.com/pages/login/Login.aspx")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form > input:nth-child(3)").send_keys("hiddenlogin")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form > input:nth-child(6)").send_keys("hiddenpw")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".m-col-12:nth-child(8)").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# go to rent reasonableness analysis
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".not-now-btn").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".clear-fix > div > .rent-btn-row > .primary-button").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)



# template code for loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933061/looping-through-several-columns-and-rows-from-csv-to-fill-a-form

    
address = driver.find_element(By.ID, "SubjectPage_AutocompleteAddress")
unit = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'SubjectPage_AddressLine2_Auto')
beds = driver.find_element(By.ID, "SubjectPage_BedroomCount")
baths = driver.find_element(By.ID, "SubjectPage_FullBathCount")
rent = driver.find_element(By.ID, "SubjectPage_AskingRent")
# unittype fix later!



for address1, unit1, unittype1, beds1, bath1, rent1 in zip(address1, unit1, unittype1, beds1, bath1, rent1):
    
    address.send_keys(address1)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    unit.send_keys(unit1)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    #unit.send_keys(unittype)
    #driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    beds.send_keys(beds1)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    baths.send_keys(bath1)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    rent.send_keys(rent1)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#SubjectPage_PropertyType_Fake > select").click()
    dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#SubjectPage_PropertyType_Fake > select")
    dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = 'Apartment']").click()
    submit = driver.find_element(By.ID, "SubjectPage_AnalyzeBottom").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the python [sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) function to achieve a delay in seconds before the loop starts. Be careful with this because it is not running based on a condition except time. If you have a large data or if you experience delay in form processing this timer will still cause the sleep function to time out and the loop will begin running. I will suggest you set a condition to be true before running the loop. For example, set a variable to True if the form is completed. Then while that condition remains true run the loop. But the loop will need to set the variable's value to false when it is done looping and loading the data.

Comment: Thanks, how would I add a few seconds of delay after the loop begins, just prior to reiterating of the loop sequence?

Comment: Correct. The delay can be placed just before the code for the loop starts so the timer runs before your loop. Please take a look at this **[link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep)** to help you understand how to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard! the sleep function works to solve one part of my problem. How would I change this code so that I would not loop but run the script for a specific row in the csv file? The script would need to be re-run for each row.

Comment: Welcome Juzek. For the 2nd part I will rather create a function for the loop so that it runs only when it is called. For e.g., create a function that only takes in args needed to update the record per line as you stated. The `for loop` will be in inside this function to take the record and load it as desired.  Make sure if you are displaying it on a table then new records are getting appended to the old table and not creating new tables (I believe that is what you intend doing). Running specific scripts at specific times can easily be achieved using functions since they only run when called.